# Instaniate objects on Raycast

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, instantiation, raycasting

So, I want the code to instantiate clone objects onto the new Raycast points if the int i<Random.Range

I have a code that allows to position an object onto the other object by Raycast. Here it is:

```
public bool RCnn;
public bool RCCheck;
void Update()
{
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SelectableTrunk>())
        {
            RandomSTrunk.position = hit.point;
            RandomSTrunk.LookAt(hit.transform.position + hit.transform.forward, hit.normal);
        for (int i = 0; i < RandomSTRUNKnumber; i++)
        {
            Transform clone = Instantiate(RandomSTrunk);
         }
            RCnn = false;
            RCCheck = false;
        }else
        {
            RCnn = true;
            RCCheck = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am passing RCNN and RCCheck to the other script and make a loop to change raycast point until it hits the place I need to be hit:

```
    Childnumber = childRC1.RCnn;
    Childcheck = childRC1.RCCheck;
    while (Childnumber == true)
    {
        if (TrunkScale < 0.75f)
        {
        RandomMinMax = Random.Range(1.0f, 0.3f);
        transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, RandomMinMax, 0.0f);
        }
    if (Childcheck == false)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (Childcheck == true)
    {
    break;
    }
    }
```

I cannot understand the way to clone the object for example 3 times and place them into  3 new Raycast hit points after checking if those points are hit. And after that remove previous positions and do everything again by pressing a button.

In my opinion, there is some stuff in the "for" loop, but I do not know where to implement it.

Comment: Nothing sets rcnn to true. Nothing instantiates. So this question is far too vague.

Comment: @BugFinder I've edited the code. It instantiates the object. However, it is creating an infinite number of clones. And also it is not working in the way of Pick a place --> Instantiate object --> Pick another place (rerunning "i" times).  I will be grateful if you or anyone can help me with it ;)

Comment: You don't have anything disabling the instantiation code. Every Update, which is every frame, you're going to instantiate RandomSTRUNKnumber objects. Your variable names are not helpful and you haven't said what RandomSTrunk is but if that also has this script attached to it then you're going to exponentially instantiate objects.